# viewing DBF file visual foxpro 9

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro, dbf

I want to open and view data from a dbf file from a old application.
I have copied the dbf file from the server share onto my PC, downloaded DBF viewers but all i showing is headed row. ab ab ab ab file access is denied.

Am i missing something else or does the file have some security.

many thanks

Comment: Some questions: 1) You say "OLD APPLICATION" - how do you know that it is a Visual Foxpro 9 data table?     2) What version of DBF Viewer did you download (DBF Viewer, DBF Viewer 2000, DBF Viewer Plus, or what)?  3) Is the DBF Viewer a TRIAL version or a FULL version? 4) Did you copy All of the associated DBF files (DBF, CDX or IDX, FPT)?

Comment: 1) Document notes it is version 9 2) DBF viewer 2000 3) trail 4)no just the one file.

Comment: Many times the TRIAL version will only work on a limited number of records.  If this is BUSINESS CRITICAL it should be worth getting the FULL version.   And you might want to get the other associated files (if they exist) to ensure that their absence would not introduce a problem.

Comment: You need to grab the associated files: YourTable.FPT and YourTable.CDX

Comment: "Access denied" immediately tells that there are missing permissions or file-in-use problem. Or a totally broken program :D

Answer (score 3):

Do you have Microsoft Access? The import wizard in that can import directly from DBF files into an Access table.

Alternatively, download [vrunfox9.zip](http://leafe.com/download/vrunfox9.zip). You might need the [Visual FoxPro 9 runtimes](http://www.foxpert.com/download/VFP9SP2RT.exe) installed too.

Run it and you will get a simulated Visual FoxPro command window.

Type:

```
use ?
```

and press enter, then locate your DBF and open it. You can then type:

```
browse
```

to view it directly. You can export it to CSV:

```
copy to myfile.csv type csv
```

or XLS:

```
copy to myfile.xls type xl5
```